# HTML Horizontal Menu Layout

Tags: html, css

I have a Hortizontal Menu at this URL - http://www.balibar.co/main.php

I'm happy with the look but I'm finding 2 things

1. it doesn't take up the entire space... there is a little white space at the end.
2. If I change the screen size (eg: hold Ctrl & use the Mouse Wheel to change the screen size) the last menu item 'search' drops to the next level.

How can i fix these 2 things.

Here is the HTML code:

```
  <div id="containerNavigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="headerLoginLink">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="headerLanguageLink">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a id="headerSearchLink">Mail</a></li>
                <li><a id="headerSearchLink">Requests</a></li>
                <li><a id="headerSearchLink">Matches</a></li>
                <li><a id="headerSearchLink">Search</a></li>            
            </ul>
  </div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
 div#containerNavigation {
width: 700px;
height: 25px;
float: left;
 }

 div#containerNavigation ul {
list-style: none;
color: #FFF;
 }

 div#containerNavigation li {
background: white url(../images/online-dating-main/navigation5.png) repeat-x 0 0;
display: inline;
line-height: 25px;
font-size: 1.1em;
float: left;
 }

 div#containerNavigation li a {
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: normal;
float: left;
width: 116px;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
text-align: center;
 }

 div#containerNavigation li a:hover {
background-color: #849C00;
 }
```

thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div#containerBody` width should be **702px**. It is less by **2px** and is the reason it is falling down ( **116 * 6 + 6 = 702** ). **6** addition is for the border right 1px for each you passed. That should be same for `containerNavigation` too.

There are few things to change.

```
div#joinHeader li a {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```

You have fixed width for the `ul` tag ( `class=shadow` ). Take out that margin 15 px for the `li a` tags. That should make them properly aligned fitting to the division. Also, `joinCatchPhrase` has extra width of 100px. Reduce it by the same.

Comment: added 702px... still falls down... should I use absolute positioning them?

Comment: you should modify for `containerNavigation` also.

Comment: yep I'll do that... do you know how I would wrap it in a table by chance?

Comment: table is not yet all required. Infact, the way you are doing is correct.

Comment: ok... thankyou... one more question... I've put the updated code up there... How can I get the space at the end to not show up as white... i see other sites that have a similar menu but the last button (li) stills right at the end - not with white space...

Comment: In that case, make the div width as **701px**. And for the last li item pass a seperate css style whose margin-right is 0px.

Answer (score 0):

Two little changes:

for the `div#containerNavigation li a`

```
width: 100%;
```

for the `div#containerNavigation li`

```
width: 116px;
```

Comment: I've make these 2 changes and its better but when I change the screen size (ctrl and mouse scroll) the last box (search) still drops off... is this fixable?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to not use a table? That way you're guaranteed to never have the problem of an item going to the next line.

Comment: how would I use a table... just wrap each li in a td ya?

Comment: Make the `<ul>` a `<table><tr>` and each `<li>` a `<td>`.